# Check whether $_POST-value is empty

Tags: php, if-statement, string

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['userName'])) {
        $username = 'Anonymous';
    }      
    else $username = $_POST['userName'];
}
```

I cannot get the `$username` to be "Anonymous"? It is either blank or the value of  `$_POST['userName']`.

Comment: isset value checks if the variable has been set already. however when you submit a form a variable will be an empty string.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will return true if the variable has been initialised. If you have a form field with its `name` value set to `userName`, when that form is submitted the value will always be "set", although there may not be any data in it.

Instead, [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the string and test its length

```
if("" == trim($_POST['userName'])){
    $username = 'Anonymous';
}
```

Comment: is it safe to use global variable directly with out sanitizing or escaping them ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds in the above example the variable isn't being used any further than to be compared. If it were changing context (i.e. output to HTML/JSON, used in a datastore query etc) then it should be treated as untrusted and dealt with context-appropriately.

Comment: @Andy Only works if the control is successful. Does not work with unchecked checkboxes in PHP. `trim()` only remove bad stuff from the ends. Not a universal solution. Makes assumptions about the input. Will fail if the `userName` key does not exist in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 49):

If the form was successfully submitted, `$_POST['userName']` should always be set, though it may contain an empty string, which is different from not being set at all. Instead check if it is [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['userName'])) {
        $username = 'Anonymous';
    } else { 
        $username = $_POST['userName'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sets one up for a precedent that says "ambiguous empty values should be ignored." This may be question specific complete, but it is not universally complete. Do not use this solution as a general solution for all textboxes, or you will encounter logic errors.

Answer (score 15):

To check if the property is present, irrespective of the value, use:

```
if (array_key_exists('userName', $_POST)) {}
```

To check if the property is set (property is present and value is not `null` or `false`), use:

```
if (isset($_POST['userName'])) {}
```

To check if the property is set and not empty (not an empty string, `0` (integer), `0.0` (float), `'0'` (string), `null`, `false` or `[]` (empty array)), use:

```
if (!empty($_POST['userName'])) {}
```

Comment: The first use case is the most technically accurate solution, but it cannot beat the speed of the second use case.The third use case is a code that should be avoided for scalar values due to ambiguity. Naturally, I am talking about `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, not JSON.

Answer (score 8):

**Question:** Check whether a $_POST value is *empty*.

**Translation:** Check to see if an array key/index has a value associated with it.

Answer: Depends on your emphasis on security. Depends on what is allowed as valid input.

```
1. Some people say use empty().
```

From the PHP Manual:

> "[Empty] determines whether a variable is considered to be empty. A
> variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value
> equals FALSE."

The following are thus considered empty.

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

If none of these values are valid for your input control, then `empty()` would work. The problem here is that `empty()` might be *too broad* to be used consistently (the same way, for the same reason, on different input control submissions to `$_POST` or `$_GET`). A good use of `empty()` is to check if an *entire array* is empty (has no elements).

```
2. Some people say use isset().
```

`isset()` (a language construct) cannot operate on entire arrays, as in `isset($myArray)`. It can only operate on *variables* and *array elements* (via the index/key): `isset($var)` and `isset($_POST['username'])`. The `isset()`language construct does two things. First it checks to see if a variable or array index/key has a value associated with it. Second, it checks to make sure that value is not equal to the PHP NULL value.

In short, the most accurate check can be accomplished best with `isset()`, as some input controls do not even register with $_POST when they are not selected or checked. I have never known a form that submitted the PHP NULL value. None of mine do, so I use `isset()` to check if a `$_POST` key has no value associated with it (and that is not NULL). `isset()`is a *much stricter test* of emptiness (in the sense of your question) than `empty()`.

```
3. Some people say just do if($var), if($myArray), or if($myArray['userName']) to determine emptiness.
```

> You can test anything that evaluates to *true* or *false* in an if
> statement. Empty arrays evaluate to false and so do variables that are
> not set. Variables that contain the PHP NULL value also evaluate to
> false. Unfortunately in this case, like with `empty()`, many more
> things also  evaluate to false: 1. the empty string '', zero (0),
> zero.zero (0.0), the string zero '0', boolean false, and certain empty
> XML objects.
>
> --Doyle, Beginning PHP 5.3

In conclusion, use `isset()` and consider combining it with other tests. Example:

May not work due to superglobal screwiness, but would work for other arrays without question.

```
if (is_array($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    // Now test for your successful controls in $_POST with isset()
}
```

Hence, why look for a value associated with a key before you even know for sure that `$_POST` represents an array and has any values stored in it at all (something many people fail to consider)? Remember, people can send data to your form without using a web browser. You may one day get to the point of testing that `$_POST` only has the allowed keys, but that conversation is for another day.

Useful reference:

[PHP Manual: Type Testing Comparison Tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: `is_array($_POST) && !empty($_POST)` is an illogical / inappropriate use of `empty()`.  First, superglobals like `$_POST` are always declared, so there is no use in checking if it is declared.  Second, if it was a variable that might not be declared, then you should be checking `!empty()` before calling `is_array()`.  `empty()` or `isset()` should be called before other functions to ensure that the variable is declared.  In my opinion, too many developers don't know how/when to use `isset()` and `empty()` nor what they actually do.

Comment: The strict test of is_array is not illogical, but your reasoning do about it is. Nothing prevents an unfortunate redefinition of a superglobal that I am aware of. Anyway, if you're still using $_POST in 2022, then you need to upgrade your code.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge `$_POST` is still relevant for adding a few forms in a mostly static website; or when you write your own framework... Even so, It's safer to set it yourself with `$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);`.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!(isset($_POST['userName']))){
    $username = 'Anonymous';
    }      
    else $username = $_POST['userName'];
}
```

To this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['userName'])){
     $username = $_POST['userName'];
}

if(empty($_POST['userName'])){
     $username = 'Anonymous';
}
```

Comment: You might want to try this out for yourself

Comment: Looking at this from the top floor, I hope people understand that a form specific solution to checking for values in `$_POST` is not a general or universal approach to doing this. Checking for emptiness should **never** be the first test of form input. Never.

Answer (score 3):

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($username == '') {$username = 'Anonymous';}
```

Best practice - always filter inputs, sanitize string is ok, but you're better off using a custom callback function to really filter out what's not acceptable.
Then check the now-safe variable if it is null/empty and if it is, set to Anonymous.  Does not require 'else' statement as it was set if it existed on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

i'd use a simple one line comparisant for these use cases

```
$username = trim($_POST['userName'])?:'Anonymous';
```

This is for the use case you are certain error logging is off so you don't get a warning that the variable isn't initialised.

this is the paranoid version:

```
$username = !empty(trim(isset($_POST['userName'])?$_POST['userName']:''))?$_POST['userName']:'Anonymous';
```

This implements a check if the `$_POST` variable is set. before accessing it.

Comment: If value is "0", then variable will be NULL. Do not use it.

Comment: @Erikas I modified it so it doesn't fail on 0.

Comment: @Tschallacka Misses the point of checking to see if an essential key/value pair exists from and HTTP POST request. If a mandatory key is not present, it's time to reject the HTTP POST input as soon as possible. Good intentions, but your solution is monolithic and lacks flexibility. If a key/value pair is not mandatory (as in a form with checkboxes), you would be providing a value to a variable that should not exist.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Yes, but in this case it's a username. not a checkbox. And do take a look at the question: `I cannot get the $username to be "Anonymous"? It...`

Comment: @Tschallacka I am looking at the question. It is not asking what to do if the `userName` value is the empty string. The code is checking for the existence of the key `userName` in `$_POST`. Thus, the conclusion of the code is wrong. If the key does not exist, then the submission is deviant, probably a hack, and should be terminated as soon as possible. Assigning the string "Anonymous" to `userName` in this scenario is just wrong. A good answer to a bad solution is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

isset is testing whether or not the key you are checking in the hash (or associative array) is "set". Set in this context just means if it knows the value. Nothing is a value. So it is defined as being an empty string.

For that reason, as long as you have an input field named userName, regardless of if they fill it in, this will be true. What you really want to do is check if the userName is equal to an empty string ''

Comment: The tests cannot be exclusive of one another. Even for a textbox, you must first check to see if the `userName` key exists. Just because you make a form, does not mean the world has to use it to send your application data. Don't assume your form will be used to send your app data. If the key is vital, mandatory, but missing in $_POST, then it is time for form processing to terminate.