# How to check if an input passed in $_POST is not empty?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether $_POST-value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154719/check-whether-post-value-is-empty)

I am using this code to validate if the passed input is not empty, but this fails when I use "white space" in the input. It does pass the empty() check.

```
if (empty($_POST['r_user'])) {
    $data['error'] = 'Please pick a username to continue.';
    $data['errorID'] = 'r_user';
}
```

What is the proper method to check an empty string in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `trim function` before checking the variable.

```
$trimUser= trim ($_POST['r_user']);
```

now execute the empty method.

Answer (score 2):

as per [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) suggestion, your code would become:

```
if (trim($_POST['r_user']) == false) {
    $data['error'] = 'Please pick a username to continue.';
    $data['errorID'] = 'r_user';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes white space  from the beginning and end of a string

working example

```
      $test = "      ";
      if(trim($test)){
         if (empty($test))
             echo "true";
         else
             echo "false";
      }
```

live : check this on [codepad](http://codepad.org/MAlHMslu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trim](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) nicely here, it removes whitespace front and back:

```
if (empty(trim($_POST['r_user']))) { // Incorrect!
```

Edit, wow, learned a new thing today.

This will however work:

```
$var=trim($_POST['r_user']);
if (empty($var)) {
```

Working Example:

```
 <?php 
    $var='    ';
    $var=trim($var);
    if(empty($var))
        echo "Yay";
    else
        echo "Nay!";

 ?>
```

Output:

> Yay

Comment: PHP docs warn that `empty(trim())` produces an error.

Comment: http://codepad.org/7QuJPRrF - produces an error. Have to trim it first, then check if it's empty.

Comment: Okay, learned a new thing about trim, but the code above now works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( empty( trim( $_POST['r_user'] ))) {
```

// wrong! gives an error - learned something new :)
// the right way should be :

```
$myvar = trim( $_POST['r_user'] ); 

if ( empty( $myvar )) {
```

or

```
if ( trim( $_POST['r_user'] ) != '' ) {
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php specifies that empty(trim()) will produce an error.

Comment: I doubt you use the first one, since you can't pass functions to `empty()`

Comment: Mistake ^^ sorry, learned something new :)

Comment: so you also learnt after fluflleh very nice of you :):):):):)

Comment: No offense, but you should probably edit out the sentence stating that you 'usually use' something that doesn't work :^)

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
$var = '';
if (array_key_exists('r_user', $_POST)) {
  $var = trim($_POST['r_user']);
} 
if (empty($var)) {
   // do some stuffs
}
```

instead.

Comment: You can't pass a function to `empty()`

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['r_user'])){
           // ur code
           }
```