# php/ mysql - Sending multiple data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to store information in MySQL and have run into an issue. Only the 'name' is stored in MySQL even though I am trying to store both name and total. I have tried to use email instead of total but still it is not stored, this tells me it is not a variable specific problem?

Currently I have this code:

```
<?php

require 'cart.php';

define('DB_NAME', 'orders');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected) {
    die('Unable to use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

...

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (name, total) VALUES ('$name', '$total')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

Here is my whole cart.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$page = 'index.php';

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('cart') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['add']] +='1';
            header('Location: order.php');

        }
    }
    header('Location: order.php');

}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
    header ('Location: order.php');

}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
    header ('Location: order.php');
}



function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id ASC');
if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
    echo "There are no products to display.";
}
else {
    echo "<center>\n";
    echo "  <table class='menufinal' border=0 width=75%>\n";
    echo "      <tr>\n";
    echo "      <th>View</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Dish</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Description</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Item Price</th>\n";
    echo "      </tr>\n";
    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="template.png" height="110" width="110"/> </td>
        <td> <?echo '<p><strong>'.$get_row['name'] . '</strong>'?> </td>
        <td> <?echo $get_row['description']?> </td>
        <td><strong> <?echo '<br>&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'"><button>Add</button></a></p>';?> </strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?
    } 
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "</center>\n";
}
} 

function cart() {

$output = '';
$output .= '<center>';
$output .= '<table class="menufinal" border=0 width=75%>';
$output .= '<tr>';
$output .= '<th>Remove Item</th>';
$output .= '<th>Item Name</th>';
$output .= '<th>Item Price</th>';
$output .= '<th>Quantity</th>';
$output .= '<th>Line Total</th>';
$output .= '</tr>';

foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0){
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
           while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td><a href="cart.php?delete=' .$id.'"><img src="x.png"></a><br></td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $get_row['name'] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>&pound ' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2) . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td><a href="cart.php?remove=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"><strong>- </strong></a>' .$value. '<a href="cart.php?add=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"> +</a></td>';
                $output .= '<td>&pound ' . number_format($sub, 2) . '</td>';
                $output .= '</tr>';
            }
        } 
        if (empty($total)) {

            if (empty($sub)) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $total = $sub;
            }
        } else {
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
}

$output .= '</table>';

if (empty($total)){
    header ('Location: index.php');
    exit;    
}

$output .=  '<br><br><br><br><div id="finalPrice">Total: &pound ' . number_format($total, 2) . '<br></div>';
$output .=  '<br><br><br><p><a href="index.php"><img src="dishes.png" width="240" height="152"></a> <img src="spacer.png" width="110"> <a href="checkout.php"><img src="checkout.png" width="240" height="151"></a>';

echo $output;
}

?>
```

If I need to show more code please let me know.

Comment: Is `$total` being set correctly?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @andrewsi updated my question showing where total is set

Comment: @JamesPatterson - but you're using `$total = $_POST['total'];` - if you're setting it in another file, that will be over-written.

Comment: @andrewsi Oh :( How can I call total to be stored, instead? I am new to programming

Comment: @JamesPatterson - I'd suggest just deleting that line. That will mean the earlier value will be used instead.

Comment: @andrewsi I deleted the line but still nothing is stored in the total field :( So frustrating! Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @JamesPatterson - `var_dump($total)` and `var_dump($sql)` will show you exactly what's being stored in those two variables.

Comment: please post the table structure

Comment: @detailer updated with whole cart.php

Comment: @JamesPatterson - a couple of things. You have a function called `cart()`, but as far as I can see, you're never actually calling it, so it never runs to generate the total. Secondly, you're setting `$total` inside that function, but because of variable scope, it won't be usable outside - you need to store the value somewhere, perhaps by using a global variable.

Comment: could you give me an example of this @andrewsi? Ive been stuck on this issue for so long now

Comment: If `$total` is an integer, I would suggest using `$total` (instead of `'$total'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of linked issues here. Your `cart` function is effectively:

```
function cart() {

    //print some stuff

    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if (empty($total)) {

            if (empty($sub)) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $total = $sub;
            }
        } else {
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
}
```

You're setting a variable called `$total` inside your function, but PHP treats that as what's called a local variable - that's a variable that exists within the function itself, but not outside of it. Likewise, variables that are set outside the function can't be used inside it unless you explicitly make them available - this is called *variable scope*.

There are a few ways to access variables set inside functions. Since you're using `$_SESSION` already, I'd suggest using this:

```
function cart() {
    $total = 0;

    //print some stuff

    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if (! empty($sub)) {
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['total'] = $total;
}
```

I'm initialising `$total` at the start of the function, so you don't need to check if it exists before trying to add to it. I'm also setting a variable in the session, which you can use outside the function.

Secondly - you need to call your function before you can use it. None of your code above is calling your function - all you need to do is have a line with `cart();` on it.

Then, when you're setting the variables for the database, you can use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$total = $_SESSION['total'];
```

A couple of other things - `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and will be removed from a future version of PHP. You shouldn't really be using them for new code now - `mysqli_` functions are fairly easy to switch to, and let you use prepared statements, which help you make your code more secure; and there's also the `PDO` library, which isn't as direct to switch code over to, but which isn't tied in to a specific database.

Also - and this is a personal preference - your `cart()` function is printing out the contents of the cart, as well as doing some calculations on it. I try to have functions that do one single thing, rather than lump them together, even if they do fit. In this case, you could have a `print_cart()` function and a `get_cart_total()` function - I find that it's a lot easier to maintain code that's written that way.

Comment: This worked but the total price isnt calculating correctly :( Is there any reason for this? Should I update my code again?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that `$sub` is set inside your loop, which means that each iteration of the loop will re-set it. You can try `$total += $get_row['price']*$value;` instead of your existing `$sub = $get_row['price']*$value;`, and delete the final `if` statement after the loop

Comment: I tried this and now I get an error stating: "Notice: Undefined variable: sub in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/IT2B/cart.php on line 92
" :(

Comment: Ack. I didn't notice you were using it in your output, too. Try putting `$sub = $get_row['price']*$value;` back in, and adding `$total += $sub;` on the following line.

Answer (score 0):

If `NULL` or `blank` is being inserted for a value in the row it means that the value has not been set correctly as @andrewsi has said in the comments.

You need to add a check for the `$_POST` variables your attempting to use, to verify that they are being sent correctly.

You also need to check the form (or other places) that this specific PHP is requested from.

In the code above you could use the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154726/1688441

**Example:**

```
if(isset($_POST['total']) && "" != trim($_POST['total'])){
    echo "Do what you need here";
}      
else
{
  die("Incorrect input sent to POST variable total.");
}
```

### Update

If your setting the value of `total` in `cart.php` you should not try to assign from `$_POST` unless your sending through post. Just delete the line `$total = $_POST['total'];`.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of how to fix this? I am new to programming so it is difficult for me to work this out

Comment: I deleted that line as suggested by andrew but still nothing gets stored :(