# Unexpected result php if statements

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

When I submit an empty form the success message is displayed and am not sure why. It shouldn't pass the first if statement if anything is left blank, why is it displaying this?

I previously had the if statement use variables but then changed them because of undefined index errors. A form with any missing fields should display the error message shown in the code

php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'db/connect.php';
    $error='';
    $success='';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

        if ( (isset($_POST['Forename'])) && (isset($_POST['Surname'])) && (isset($_POST['Gender'])) && (isset($_POST['YearGroup'])) ) {
            /*print_r($_POST);*/

            $forename = $_POST['Forename'];
            $surname = $_POST['Surname'];
            $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
            $yeargroup = $_POST['YearGroup'];

            //To protect MySQL injection
            $forename= stripslashes($forename);
            $surname = stripslashes($surname);
            $forename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $forename);
            $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $surname);

            if ($teacher_form = $con->query("SELECT Form FROM teacher WHERE Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")) {
                $row1 = $teacher_form->fetch_assoc(); 
                $form = $row1['Form'];
                $con->query("INSERT INTO student (Forename, Surname, Gender, Year_group, Form) VALUES (\"" . $forename ."\", \"" . $surname . "\", \"" . $gender . "\", " . $yeargroup . ", \"" . $form . "\")   ");
                $success = 'Student has been successfully added to the database';                           
            }
        }   

        else {
            $error='All fields must be completed';
        }   
    }           
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'db/checkuserloggedin.php';
    include 'db/header.php';
    include 'addstudent.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add students</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="logoutbutton">
            <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='logout.php'">Logout</button>'
        </div>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
            <?php echo "<form method =\"POST\">"; ?>
                <h3> Add student </h3>
                    <table>                             
                        <tr>            
                            <td>Forename</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Forename"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>                
                            <td>Surname</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Surname"></td> 
                        </tr>

                        <tr>            
                            <td>Gender</td>
                            <td><select name ="Gender"> 
                              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                              <option> M </option>
                              <option> F </option>                                                              
                              </select> <br>                        
                            </td>                   
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Year group</td>
                            <td><select name ="YearGroup">
                            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>            
                            <option> 7 </option>
                            <option> 8 </option>
                            <option> 9 </option>
                            <option> 10 </option>
                            </select> <br>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="Add">
                <input type="reset" value ="Reset"> <br>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error;?></span> 
                <span class="error"><?php echo $success;?></span>                   
            <?php echo "</form>"; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change all `(isset($_POST['Forename']))` -> `!empty($_POST['Forename'])`

Comment: thankyou @Rizier123 I believe this has worked, why did the first statement give an unexpected result?

Comment: Because isset only checks that the variable is set, but it doesn't check if the variable is empty or not

Comment: _"It shouldn't pass the first if statement if anything is left blank"_ You meant the _second_ if statement, and this is still not true. Where did you hear that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns false only if the variable is not defined or is null.

Your input fields always exist in your form so **users will post empty values** even if they don't populate every field. *Empty* and *null* are different in PHP.

It is a good practice to check that every key of the `$_POST` array is defined as you would expect. It protects you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities.

But you also want to check that the defined keys contain a non-empty value. I would recommend you to use the following check for every input:

```
if (isset($_POST['Forename']) && $_POST['Forename'] !== '') {
    ...
}
```

There is also an [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function that does both these checks in one call:

```
if (!empty($_POST['Forename'])) {
    ...
}
```

Note that the latter doesn't work if your user enters a **0** (zero) in one of the fields as this is considered as an *empty* value.

If one of your fields can potentially contain a valid **0** value (e.g. number of children, years of experience...), fall back a combination of `isset($var)` and `$var !== ''`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154734/2815792) may give you a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use empty function and replace && operator with ||

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

            if ( (empty($_POST['Forename'])) || (empty($_POST['Surname'])) || (empty($_POST['Gender'])) || (empty($_POST['YearGroup'])) ) {
```

Comment: Or you may use `$_POST['Forename'] == NULL`