# Add $_POST to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

Can I insert new record from `$_POST` to MySQL database via PHP?

**My PHP current code:**

```
<?php
    // if text data was posted
    if($_POST){
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
(
    [tokenID] => f0g6dSwx_R4:APA91bGic-JFlhehUz6pl2CUqw_8j1OATMXRmrnMjuBXJhzrnIU3pxDJGrpb7jCZpAR4yG8SJWPczxnY9AL1EC03FBnoH6Y6JYTO_Xge92QRXgbuW8u_EfbNAF077dFtlg2w_B__4dv2
    [name] => SIT-Messanger
    [token] => f0g6dSwx_R4:APA91bGic-JFlhehUz6pl2CUqw_8j1OATMXRmrnMjuBXJhzrnIU3pxDJGrpb7jCZpAR4yG8SJWPczxnY9AL1EC03FBnoH6Y6JYTO_Xge92QRXgbuW8u_EfbNAF077dFtlg2w_B__4dv2
    [email] => miketestmailcom
)
```

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is learn some php code of basic insert/update/delete/get.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154719/check-whether-post-value-is-empty

Comment: the only answer that can be given to that question is `yes`. but I doubt that helps you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First create new table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (
    tokenID varchar(250), 
    name varchar(100), 
    token varchar(250),
    email varchar(100)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Or use insert statement

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('tokenID', 'name','token','email');
```

Comment: If you're going to run the code everything you'd have to do CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS. Or just run it once manually then remove the code since it should never delete itself

Comment: good idea i update my answer :) @HamzahMalik